# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

I got this error when I run my project. There's no error with the code, but I think the error maybe caused by the dependencies in gradle. Anyone can help?

here's the error message:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:       org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

and here is my build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "link.dr.daniel.tickme"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Anyone know? thank you very much.

Comment: build -> clean project

Comment: @hello_world it didn't work

Comment: it generally works for me. try restating android studio. its an internal error, nothing to do with your code.

Comment: try file >> invalidate crashes and restart

Comment: Hi, I had this line leftover from when I included a map in my app, now is no longer needed: "compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'" It never caused any problems, but all of a sudden I started getting the same error. If you have that value in the app's gradle build ( or control + H to find it in the project ) and it is no longer required, comment it out. If you can't find it, just search for "multidex". Also, install updates if there is any available. Close Android Studio, restard and good luck!

Comment: @hello_world I have tried your solutions but It still didn't work.. I have even uninstalled and re-installed the android studio, but I still face the same problem.

Comment: @humazed I have tried your solutions but It still didn't work.. I have even uninstalled and re-installed the android studio, but I still face the same problem.

Comment: @Dan I have tried your solutions but It still didn't work.. I have even uninstalled and re-installed the android studio, but I still face the same problem.